# How to export excel file to csv file without the semicolon outside the inserted values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, csv, office365

I have inserted values into excel file in "order_status" sheet. These values are shown in below picture:

[image]

In this sheet I added data validations like: dynamic drop down list, checking if in cell is only number and checking if date in cell is more than 2005-05-05.  I'm using in  MS Excel Microsoft Business 365. I have version 1903 (compilation 11425.20228). The .xlsx file has about 36 MB. When i export this sheet into .csv file it has about 11 MB. However it should have smaller size. Because when i would edit in text editor i have these inserted values.

```
ID_WORKER;FNAME;LNAME;DESC_ORDER;NUMBER_ORDER;NAME;PROJECT_NAME;AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS;BEGIN_DATE;END_DATE
1;Paul;King;Making cables;OR/3;V 435;luck;30;2019-05-25 06:45:25;2019-05-25 15:24:35
3;Martin;Goat;Reworking modules;OR/8;V5;das;50;2019-05-25 06:50:31;2019-05-25 15:10:04
5;Conrad ;Kich;Reworking modules;OR/8;V6 25;dfa;15;2019-05-25 06:55:33;2019-05-25 15:28:21
14;Theresa;Anna;zp/11;OR/1;V 32143;cc;5;2019-05-25 06:44:54;2019-05-25 13:33:21
14;Theresa;Anna;Programming;OR/9;V 435;gfd;32;2019-05-25 06:39:44;2019-05-25 15:05:22
8;Matthew;Uncle;zp/11;OR/1;V5;das;44;2019-05-25 06:55:32;2019-05-25 15:22:22
6;David;All;ZP/123;OR/5;V 435;cc;22;2019-05-25 06:56:44;2019-05-25 15:15:21
9;Catherine;Gumul;Wiring;OR/7;V 435;kadir;31;2019-05-26 06:52:22;2019-05-26 15:21:22
10;Paul;Afternoon;Reworking;OR/2;V6 66;luck;1;2019-05-26 06:48:33;2019-05-26 15:45:21
3;Martin;Goat;Counterfeiting of cables;OR/6;V7 32;kadir;12;2019-05-26 06:53:33;2019-05-26 15:33:21
12;Martin;Wolf;Reworking wires;OR/4;V6 16;das;15;2019-05-27 06:51:11;2019-05-27 15:21:22
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
```

.
.
.

There not only rows with column names and the inserted vales but there are unnecessary semicolons.

I have a question: How can i save file into .csv file without semicolns? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excess lines with semicolons means that somewhere there was any data in the range below current last line. Select these excess lines, delete them (rows, not data), then export.

Comment: Alternatively - copy data which must be saved into newly created worksheet/workbook, save it as CSV, then remove.

Comment: @Akina to the first comment how to delete them? To delete data validations in excel file?

Comment: If your data validations posessed below last data row, and they cannot be removed, you can do nothing... use special copy - values only into new sheet/book and save it. Or you can create VBA procedure which exports your data (or processes the CSV and removes excess lines).

Comment: Wait i forgot mention that in excel sheet till the end are written automatic formulas which after selecting value one of cells the second cell is automatically written. So i can't only "clear values".

Comment: But Copy-PasteSpecial is available nevertheless?